# accessing a variable inside foreach

Tags: makefile

How can I access a variable from outside foreach loop . I want to print index number for the record.
my code .

```
LIST=$(shell ls)
test:
i=0
@$(foreach k,$(LIST), echo "index $(i) = $k";)


Output desired is like below .  
index 0 = A
index 1 = B
index 2 = C
index 3 = D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipes should consist of shell commands, rather than make-statements, e.g:-

**Makefile**

```
LIST := $(shell ls) # This is a make-statement

test:       # This is a target
    @# And this is its recipe...
    @# So write shell commands here...
    @i=0; \
    for f in $(LIST); do \
        echo "index $$i = $$f"; \
        i=$$(expr $$i + 1); \
    done
```

or perhaps simply:

```
test:
    @i=0; \
    for f in $$(ls); do \
        echo "index $$i = $$f"; \
        i=$$(expr $$i + 1); \
    done
```

Runs like:

```
$ make
index 0 = A
index 1 = B
index 2 = C
index 3 = D
index 4 = Makefile
```